# Extern array, how to use

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, extern

I want to use external character array say of size 50.

i have extern.h

```
extern char arr[50];
```

i have a.c where i am accessing the `arr`.

and i have b.c that is my driver file.

Also i have a.h having definitions of functions in a.c

Now in my driver file b.c i have

```
#include"extern.h"
#include"a.h"
char arr[50];
int main()
{
//call to function in a.c
}
```

and in my a.c i have

```
#include"a.h"
#include"extern.h"
int function1()
{
//accessing arr, say printing arr[1]
}
```

This gives me seg fault.

Am i including the file right, and my declaration of external var in extern.h and in b.c are correct.?

What is causing the seg fault?

Comment: Don't include extern.h in b.c (main()): arr[] is defined "twice", one with extern, and the other without extern ... extern wins, so arr[] is not statically associated with an allocated array.

Comment: @ydroneaud How come "extern wins"? The array declaration "wins", otherwise you'd have a linkage error. The problem must be elsewhere (eg incorrect use of *printf*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in the way you are using *extern*.

If the *extern* declaration in b.c would hide the `char arr[50];` declaration, then you would have a linkage error.

```
extern char arr[50];
char arr[50];
int main() {
  //call to function in a.c
}
```

The problem must be elsewhere. Maybe in the way *printf* is used?

```
printf("%c\n", arr[1]);  // works
printf("%s\n", &arr[1]); // may cause a seg fault depending on arr content
```